# Emulate SSD drive in VMware Workstation 12

Tags: linux, ssd, vmware-workstation

I'm running `VMware Workstation 12`, and am trying to have it see `SCSI0:0` as an SSD drive.

I want to have the `discard` mount option and `fstrim /` work on `ext4` and `btrfs`.

I added the following to my `.vmx` file:
scsi0:0.virtualSSD = 1

But in Linux (both `Mint 17.2` and `Manjaro 16.08`, `/sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` contains `1`, meaning it gets detected as a HDD or spindle and platter disk.

However, `smartctl -a /dev/sda` disagrees:

> ```
> smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-38-generic] (local build)
> Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
>
> === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
> Vendor:               VMware,
> Product:              VMware Virtual S
> Revision:             1.0
> User Capacity:        274,877,906,944 bytes [274 GB]
> Logical block size:   512 bytes
> Rotation Rate:        Solid State Device
> Device type:          disk
> Local Time is:        Tue Oct 25 08:35:07 2016 ICT
> SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.
>
> === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
>
> Error Counter logging not supported
>
> Device does not support Self Test logging
> ```

How do I get `rotational` to be `0` (and thence get `TRIM` working?)

---

Also asked at:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187281
- https://communities.vmware.com/message/2628725#2628725
- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ssd-detected-by-smartctl-but-queue-rotational-1/11507

Comment: Are you sure VMware advertises the TRIM command for its virtual drives? What are actually trying to accomplish, auto-shrinking images?

Comment: Relevant source code: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/sd.c?v=4.7#L2731 - you could hack in a few printk to debug, see same file for example.

Comment: @Daniel B [This](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-3FBBB031-D8BA-4D02-99C2-282F806F47E8.html) seems to indicate that it should support `TRIM`. Yes, I'm trying to auto-shrink images - they are constantly [growing in size](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304903/vmware-why-is-zero-filling-ext4-free-space-needed-to-shrink-vmdk-files)

Comment: I don’t see anything indicating TRIM support there. Indeed, the only thing I found was about vSphere 6.0, but it wasn’t about auto-shrinking images. I’m quite sure VMware Workstation doesn’t support this.

Comment: @DanielB Message from the future: there is 2021, vmware workstation still no support.

Comment: @mashuptwice `queue/rotational` has nothing to do with `TRIM` / `discard` / `UNMAP`, but they all depend on what exact type of emulation we are talking about. If it's SCSI (as opposed to `SATA`), most likely there's something bad with its VPD emulations (or response to `READ CAPACITY` / `INQUIRY`), which can be hunt down with `sg3_utils`.

Answer (score -1):

Negative answer : A TRIM issued within the VM on emulated hardware
cannot be translated to a TRIM on the host
(at least to my knowledge and at the moment).

In order to auto-shrinking images, the only solution might be to schedule
a task for
[Discarding Blocks Not in Use](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/sect-domain_commands-discarding_blocks_not_in_use).

The task will use
[virsh](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/libvirt-clients/virsh.1.en.html)
with the following verb:

> **domfstrim**
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> domfstrim domain [--minimum bytes] [--mountpoint mountPoint]
> ```
>
> Issue a fstrim command on all mounted filesystems within a running
> domain. It discards blocks which are not in use by the filesystem. If
> *--minimum* **bytes** is specified, it tells guest kernel length of contiguous free range. Smaller than this may be ignored (this is a
> hint and the guest may not respect it). By increasing this value, the
> fstrim operation will complete more quickly for filesystems with badly
> fragmented free space, although not all blocks will be discarded. The
> default value is zero, meaning "discard every free block". Moreover,
> if a user wants to trim only one mount point, it can be specified via
> optional *--mountpoint* parameter.

The following example trims the file system running on the guest virtual
machine named `guest1`:

```
# virsh domfstrim guest1 --minimum 0
```