# Does VMware Workstation 12.5.1 support TRIM

Tags: ssd, vmware-workstation, trim

Does VMware Workstation 12.5.1 support [TRIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)) for a guest OS?

If so, what apart from putting:

```
scsi0:0.virtualSSD = 1
```

in the `.vmx` file, what configuration is required to get it to work?

I am trying to get `TRIM` commands passed from the guest OS to create holes in my sparse `.vmdk` file.

If it makes any difference, I'm running VMware under Win10.

Comment: [VMWare 10](http://superuser.com/a/646884/241386) supports TRIM so I assume so is VMWare 12

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I couldn't find any mention of "trim", "ssd" or "passthrough" on the page linked in your answer. Where exactly does it mention that?

Comment: The new versions removed it. You can find "SSD passthrough" in [some old cache version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101011710/http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/features.html)

Comment: I believe they removed this marketing claim from future versions because it was crippled as they didn't support TRIM. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1139128/emulate-ssd-drive-in-vmware-workstation-12) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304903/vmware-why-is-zero-filling-ext4-free-space-needed-to-shrink-vmdk-files)