# Autorun zerofree on boot (or on shutdown)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, shutdown

I have a virtualbox vitual server that keeps growing. To keep its virtual disk small I'm manually shrinking it using `VBoxManage modifyhd disk.vdi compart` after zeroing unused space on the disk using [zerofree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/zerofree.8.html) while booted to recovery mode. I would like to automatize it.

Is there a way how to run `zerofree /dev/sda1` (where `/dev/sda1` is my `/`) automatically on each server boot? Or alternatively on each server shutdown?

To run `zerofree /dev/sda1` the device `/dev/sda1` must be mounted read-only. So I can't run it while the server is running. However isn't there any chanche to run in on boot just before mounting it? Or on shutdown just after umounting?

The virtual server system is Ubutnu 16.04.

Comment: you can simply let the VM [remove unused blocks from the vdi automatically with the TRIM command](https://superuser.com/q/193650/241386)